# Scraping with xpath with requests and lxml but having problems

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml, scrape

I keep running into an issue when I scrape data with lxml by using the xpath. I want to scrape the dow price but when I print it out in python it says Element span at 0x448d6c0. I know that must be a block of memory but I just want the price. How can I print the price instead of the place in memory it is?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://markets.businessinsider.com/index/realtime- 
chart/dow_jones')
content = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of prices:
prices = content.xpath('//*[@id="site"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]/div/div/div/span')

#This will create a list of volume:


print (prices)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting generators which as you said are just memory locations. To access them, you need to call a function on them, in this case, you want the text so `.text`

Additionally, I would **highly recommend** changing your XPath since it's a literal location and subject to change.

```
prices = content.xpath("//div[@id='site']//div[@class='price']//span[@class='push-data ']")
prices_holder = [i.text for i in prices]
prices_holder
 ['25,389.06',
 '25,374.60',
 '7,251.60',
 '2,813.60',
 '22,674.50',
 '12,738.80',
 '3,500.58',
 '1.1669',
 '111.7250',
 '1.3119',
 '1,219.58',
 '15.43',
 '6,162.55',
 '67.55']
```

Also of note, you will only get the values **at load**. If you want the prices as they change, you'd likely need to use Selenium.

Comment: Maybe close the request? I'm going to look it up to see if it is possible.

Comment: `requests.get()` is getting the content on load. You could keep running but that requires reloading the page multiple times and that is gonna be taxing. Using selenium, you can load the page once, get the price at the time and then implement a wait or continually check if the price has changed and store that value in your list.

Comment: What would you recommend for me to change the xpath to, since it is a literal path?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish If you want only the top quote: `//div[@id='site']//div[@class='box table_distance realtime-pricebox']//div[@class='price']//span[@class='push-data ']`. By relying on classes, you can jump from `div` to `div` within the html tree instead of going level by level.

Comment: I’ll check that out too.

Comment: Where would i put that class? In my 'content.xpath' I am assuming, but what do I need to change it to? @W_Stokvis

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish that is an XPath. It's a way to navigate through the DOM. It's similar to what you had above in `content.xpath()` but relies on traversing the DOM using classes rather than level by level which is what happens when you Copy XPath in the DOM. It goes 1. Find a `div` where the `id` is `site`. Then look through every level (hence the double `//`) for a `div` with a `class` equal to `box table_distance realtime-pricebox` and so on.

Comment: What would I need to put into the code to make it find that class instead of going for the xpath?

Comment: XPaths are coordinates to elements. Elements have classes.  You can use attributes of elements such as classes to navigate the DOM.

Comment: Could you give me an example of it with a code to find that same text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177308/discussion-between-kamikaze-goldfish-and-w-stokvis).

Answer (score 1):

The variable `prices` is a list containing a web element. You need to call the text method to extract the value.

```
print(prices[0].text)

'25,396.03'
```