# how to scrape this certain section of html

Tags: python, html, css, python-requests

hi this is my first time really coding at all and trying to make a scraper to find all the info for my school and district

```
\[<p class="flex-icon">
\<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-school" focusable="false"\>
\<use xlink:href="#icon-school"\>\</use\>
\</svg\> \<span\><strong>School Number:</strong> K003\</span\>

</p>, <p>
   <strong>Accessibility:</strong> No Accessibility
</p>, <p>
   <strong>Grades:</strong> PK,0K,01,02,03,04,05,SE
</p>, <p>
   <strong>2020–2021 Enrollment:</strong> 257
</p>, <p>

<strong>Geographic District:</strong> 13

</p>, <p>
   <strong>Borough:</strong> Brooklyn
</p>]
```

how do i scrape just this "PK,0K,01,02,03,04,05,SE" out of this HTML using python my current code is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.schools.nyc.gov/schools/K003'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
school_detail = soup.find('div',{'class':'module school-detail'})
school_name = soup.find('h1', {'class': "title"})
address = soup.find('a', {'class': 'more'})
grade = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'flex-icon'})

grade_levels = soup.find('div', {'class': 'box'}{'','span'}).find('span')
grade = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'flex-icon'})
```

tried these two ways but nothing is really working

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS selector:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.schools.nyc.gov/schools/K003'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
el = soup.select_one(
    '.box-list > li:nth-child(3) > div > p > span')

# 1. split the string with `:` so we get the " PK,0K,01,02,03,04,05,SE" from the text
# 2. strip() for getting rid of the white space in the text content
text = el.getText().split(":")[1].strip()
print(text) # "PK,0K,01,02,03,04,05,SE"
```

Comment: thank your for your help, trying to understand the code you posted, why did did you call for .box-list is that cause the entire section coded under this? When I got and look at the page source searching for  li:nth-child(3) it shows up but its not explicit within the area that i found the grades. sorry if this didnt make any sense ```el = soup.select_one(
    '.box-list > li:nth-child(3) > div > p > span')```

Comment: Yes, it just narrows down the possibility of selecting the wrong element. `.box-list` is the only class name that appeared in the whole DOM tree. So by starting with it, I can be quite confident that I won't select something else. I don't fully understand your second question though. Do you mean you're not able to get the text content (PK,0K,01,02,03,04,05,SE)?

Comment: I do get the text content, what I meant is that I am also scrapping for names and emails of principals, is there a better way to search for those similar to this way? Like how you have it set up?

Comment: Yeah, there are other ways you can use to select the DOM tree or the text node. Xpath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637310/scraping-with-xpath-with-requests-and-lxml-but-having-problems
Or good old regular expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67388420/how-can-i-use-regex-to-help-scrape-web-data